# Expectation of product

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, iid

Let $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a finite collection of i.i.d random variables. [I have found](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342805/expectation-of-unifrom-iid-r-v-multiplied-together) that $$E[\prod_i X_i]=\prod_i E[X_i]$$ But I haven't found a proof of this fact. What is the proof?

Comment: Hint: The variables do not need to be identically distributed--only independent.  You should be able to proceed from there using only the definitions of independent and expectation.  The case of an infinite product might involve a little bit of analysis and extra assumptions.

Comment: Even in the case of [three independent variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90482/expectation-product-of-pairwise-uncorrelated-variables), if they're independent but not identically distributed, it looks like we have $E[XYZ]=cov(XY,Z)+E[X]E[Y]E[Z]$, so we'd still need to show $cov(XY, Z)$ is zero

Comment: I see. An i.i.d set implies mutual independence. Not just pairwise.